# Since devices in typical house scenario are exposed to ISP, Do anonimous OS (tails/kodachi/etc) require a different scenario to keep anonymity?

Tags: encryption, anonymity

Researching on this topic I found the answer of [Conor Mancone](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/203155/252427) for a similar question about whether [Can an ISP detect or log specific devices connected to ISP-provided home routers?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/203146/can-an-isp-detect-or-log-specific-devices-connected-to-isp-provided-home-routers), which answer was that *If you are using their device (router), then you don't really have a network of your own - your house is just an extension of their network.* (Which makes total sense to me)

So, my doubt is that It seems that the scenario of the hacker hacking from their house, or the Activist or Journalist scenario accessing the Internet from unsafe places and communicating securely, doesn't apply as simply as It looks like or requires a bit more background.

Then, pursuing a high level of anonymity and actually getting it seems to be possible in untypical scenarios.

To be anonymous, e.g. exploring the dark net, researching active treat groups or visiting their sites, and similar activities... How many technical resources are required and What these are?

Is really possible to protect yourself from door-to-door traceability? (What's the point of using Tails/Kodachi If the connection could be traced to the nearest ISP/Antena, despite that Kodachi seems not intended for beginner users)

Despite the use of an encrypted router & OS, in the end, Isn't my relative position exposed to the nearest connection endpoint (e.g. the closer ISP/Antena)?

What's needed to take into consideration when thinking about exploring the internet, and also in the dark web, to keep your identity and location "out of the range" of potential attackers, hosts, or other users?

Comment: With TOR (or the 'dark net'), your local router and your ISP may be able to see that you are using TOR.  But, they cannot see what TOR hosts you are connecting to.  And, the TOR hosts that you are connecting to cannot see your IP.  See https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/onion-services for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Many of these technologies are designed with hostile/untrusted networks in mind. Tails/Kodachi typically rely on Tor to allow for a degree of anonymity with regard to network connections. It's not very different to consider anonymity using Tor in this scenario vs any other scenario. When properly using Tor, any passive or active observer on the network can see that you are using Tor, but they cannot see your final destination or the actual contents of the traffic due to how Tor works.

So if an ISP has visibility into your home network (again, a reasonable assumption if you are using their hardware), they can probably pinpoint which devices are connecting to Tor, but they cannot tell what those devices are doing on the Tor network.

That said, if your ISP, government, or other entity is able to observe both the traffic leaving your home network, and the traffic leaving the Tor exit node, it might be possible to correlate this activity to you, even though the contents of the traffic cannot be seen at any point (assuming HTTPS is used).